# Stored Procedure insert problems

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a stored procedure I am calling to insert items in a table.  If it only inserts an item into the table I get a 'Operation aborted' exception.  If I add a select after the insert, it works fine.

What do I need to do different so I don't get the exception with only the insert?

Delphi code

```
procedure AddItem(dbCon : TADOConnection; sourcePath : String);
var
  addProc    : TADOStoredProc;


begin
  if FileExists(sourcePath) then
  begin
    try
      addProc := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
      addProc.Connection    := dbCon;
      addProc.ProcedureName := 'spTest';
      addProc.Open;

    finally
      addProc.Free();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest]
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.ToSolve (Data, SolveStatus)
  VALUES (null, 1)

  --SELECT * from dbo.ToSolve --I must have a select or I get and exception
END
```

Comment: I'm not a Delphi expert but databases typically require code to COMMIT a transaction after it has done its work. Try searching on "Delphi insert commit" to review how to do that in Delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out, [`TADOStoredProc.Open`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_Open.html) is used in cases where there is a recordset returned.
Use [`TADOStoredProc.ExecProc`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOStoredProc_ExecProc.html) when no recordsets are returned. The same goes for `TADOQuery`, use `ExecSQL` for `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements and `Open` for `SELECT` statements. So your example should be like this:

```
procedure AddItem(dbCon : TADOConnection; sourcePath : String);

var
  addProc    : TADOStoredProc;

begin
  if FileExists(sourcePath) then
  begin
    addProc := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
    try
      addProc.Connection    := dbCon;
      addProc.ProcedureName := 'spTest';
      addProc.ExecProc;    
    finally
      addProc.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had just copied and pasted a stored procedure example.